# Yii framework: chtml::button on submit pass argument

Tags: php, yii

> CHtml::button('Update',array('submit' => array('link/update', array('id'=>$data->linkId)))

The url submitted

> localhost/yiiTest2/index.php?r=link/update&0%5Bid%5D=5

Hw to remove this 0%5B and %5D????

Comment: `0%5B` is `[` and `0%5D` - `]` Are you sure they are not needed for data processing? It seems, YII framework generates itself.

Comment: They r nt required...But the link sud b link/update?id=5...

Comment: I think Yii adds the brackets to elements that are part of a form

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax for `submit` yu are usin is wrong. Try this

```
CHtml::button('Update',array('submit' => array('link/update', 'id'=>$data->linkId)))
```